# Fiddler doesn't decompress gzip responses

Tags: gzip, fiddler, compression

I use `Fiddler` to debug my application. Whenever the response is compressed by server, instead of decompressed response, Fiddler shows unreadable binary data:

```
/* Response to my request (POST) */
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: xyz.com
Date: Tue, 07 Jun 2011 22:22:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Encoding: gzip

14
����������������
0
```

How can I get the response decompressed?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I use fiddler version 2.3.4.4 and just noticed that in the Inspectors tab ("Raw" sub-tab), above the response section (in case of gzip-ed response), appears `"Response is encoded and may need to be decoded before inspection. Click here to transform."` 
If you click on that, the response becomes readable.
The settings are pretty much the default, I just installed Fiddler and did not change anything.

Comment: Well I'll be damned, I never actually read that little yellow message; like it was hidden by a [Somebody Else's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somebody_Else%27s_Problem) cloaking device.

Answer (score 28):

If you don't want to have to click per response as in the accepted answer, using the menu, click Rules -> Remove All Encodings.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Or click the DECODE button in Fiddler's toolbar.

Comment: @EricLaw actually your comment is the correct answer!

Answer (score 7):

From the fiddler faq

> Q: I like to navigate around a site then do a "search" for a text on all the logged request/responses. I was curious if Fiddler automatically decompressed gzipped responses during search?
>
> A: Fiddler does not decompress during searches by default, since it would need to keep both the compressed and decompressed body in memory (for data integrity reasons).
>
> In current versions of Fiddler, you can tick the "Decode Compressed Content" checkbox on the Find dialog.

Here is a link to the site

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/faq.asp

Comment: I want to see response text inside Fiddler but it is compressed. I don't need search it, just view it. This is necessary while debugging AJAX components.

Comment: It was the only hit I found on their site. Maybe digging into it more might yield some favorable results. : /

Comment: I think this post might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243959/how-can-i-get-asp-net-ajax-to-send-its-json-repsonse-with-gzip-compression

Comment: I coded my Fiddler plugin and it works fine, but zip library cannot decompress some websites. It says: wrong first magic byte...

Comment: That's really frustrating, I'm sorry to hear that. When you get the plugin working with those websites that are throwing errors can you share your solution?

Comment: Of course. But StackOverFlow has not such an option. I guess the problem is with HTTP headers. Some websites claim they are using Gzip while they are using other algorithms. I have used `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib`.

Comment: I ended up using `Charles web debugger` which has a 30 days free trial with more options than `Fiddler`. It is Java based. You can find it here: http://www.charlesproxy.com

Comment: If you still need the code I can upload somewhere and put the link here. Maybe you fix it and share again with others. Anyway `Charles` solved my case and I practiced coding `Fiddler` plugins!