# Abot not decoding web response properly

Tags: c#, encoding

I'm using Abot (C#) to crawl a website using the standard settings in their  [getting started documentation](https://code.google.com/p/abot/wiki/v1d5QuickStart).

After retrieving a web page I can't read the content - it doesn't appear to have been decoded correctly.

If I comment out the Abot code and just use the standard `(HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()` .net method I can see the page content correctly.

I want to use Abot for its scraping capabilities though.  But as you can see below I get a load of incorrectly decoded content.

[image]

Has anyone got any ideas on how I can fix the problem?

**EDIT:** I'm pretty sure its something to do with the website as I don't have the same problem if I run against http://www.google.com

**EDIT 2:** Here are the headers

WebRequest

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept: */*
Host: www.<website>.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

WebResponse

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 29 Jul 2015 12:28:53 GMT
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=de5028c9ea76b127d7aebe40617a7a6b51438172932; expires=Thu, 28-Jul-16 12:28:52 GMT; path=/; domain=.<website>.com; HttpOnly,PHPSESSID=e2ekece8flgs000h6u6kvf66k6; path=/,ct_cookies_test=7a1a1460017221ec70f96f0f2a3cdaac; path=/
X-Powered-By: W3 Total Cache/0.9.4.1
Expires: Wed, 29 Jul 2015 13:28:53 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
Pragma: public
X-Pingback: http://www.<website>.com/<file>.php
Link: <http://wp.me/P2xmvI-a>; rel=shortlink
Last-Modified: Wed, 29 Jul 2015 12:28:53 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 20d8d37b9fc406be-LHR
```

Comment: Already tried using a different encoding? You know what this remote pages uses as encoding? What is the expected result?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: I don't know how to try a different encoding with Abot.  The HttpWebResponse.GetResponse() is already processed by the time the page is available in the PageCrawlCompletedEvent

Comment: It looks like there is some stuff to be decompressed... (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272317/fiddler-doesnt-decompress-gzip-responses) Do you have the headers for me which are sent? (Especially the `Accept-Encoding` header)

Comment: Excuse me, I meant the request headers :)

Comment: I probably would have realised if I'd known more about the topic...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84574/discussion-between-corstian-boerman-and-drammy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko` header your response will probably be more readable. I'm not sure but it looks like the web server encodes responses sent to this user agent in some way. (I'm not an expert either)

I can recommend you to use Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to check how web requests are handled. (Which is quite nice for debugging this kind of problems)

---

[image: Fiddler bad content]

*Bad content seen in fiddler*

---

[image: Fiddler correct content]

*Correct content seen in fiddler*

Comment: Brilliant!  Cheers Corstian - I found that taking the UserAgent out (in Abot) had the same affect but when I changed it to the user agent sent by Chrome it worked!